# Python POST Request not going past login page

Tags: python, authentication, post, get, python-requests

I'm trying to log into this website, it has a hidden field which requires a unique generated key, which I got using BS, and made sure it's the same in the get and post request by using a session. However it's still displaying the login page when I print

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.75 Safari/537.36"}

url = 'https://www.unovarpg.com/login.php'


with requests.session() as s:
    load = s.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(load.text,"html5lib")
    a = soup.find('input',type='hidden')['value']
    payload = {'username':'myusername','password':'mypassword','unovarpg':a,'rememberMe':'checkbox'}
    x = s.post(url,data=payload,headers=headers)
    print(x.text)
```

Comment: use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see how and where browser send data when you login. You will see that it send it to different url - with `?doLogin` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see how and where browser send data when you login then you will see that it send it to different url - with `?doLogin` at the end.

```
https://www.unovarpg.com/login.php?doLogin
```